# Adding a ScrollViewer (via c# code) to TabPage

Tags: c#, wpf-controls

I'm trying to add a `System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer` to a `System.Windows.Forms.TabPage`, however, the function `Add(ScrollViewer)` isn't valid.

Is there some way to add a ScrollViewer to a `TabPage` that's built in, and not XAML.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you have tagged this as WPF I am guessing the reference to Forms may be wrong?

Here is an example of a page in a tab - the idea was to ensure that the toolbar remained at the top and the status bar remained at the bottom (not the MainWindow status bar...) and the content in the middle could scroll..

```
Dim vScrollViewer As New ScrollViewer
        Dim vSP As New StackPanel
        With vSP
            .HorizontalAlignment = Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch
            .VerticalAlignment = Windows.VerticalAlignment.Stretch
        End With
        Dim vInnerGrid As New Grid
        vScrollViewer.Content = vSP
        vSP.Children.Add(vInnerGrid)
```

The vScollViewer can be added to any other control (such as the middle of a three row grid)

Full event

```
Private Sub Website_WebPage_Page_Initialized(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Initialized
    Try
        Dim vScrollViewer As New ScrollViewer
        Dim vSP As New StackPanel
        With vSP
            .HorizontalAlignment = Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch
            .VerticalAlignment = Windows.VerticalAlignment.Stretch
        End With
        Dim vInnerGrid As New Grid
        vScrollViewer.Content = vSP
        vSP.Children.Add(vInnerGrid)

        Dim Col1 As New ColumnDefinition
        With Col1
            .Width = New GridLength(120)
        End With
        Dim Col2 As New ColumnDefinition
        With Col2
            .Width = New GridLength(200, GridUnitType.Star)
        End With



        With Website_WebPage_Grid
            .Background = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.White)
        End With

        With vInnerGrid
            .ColumnDefinitions.Add(Col1)
            .ColumnDefinitions.Add(Col2)
        End With



        For i As Integer = 0 To 11 ' 
            Dim vRow As New RowDefinition
            With vRow
                If i = 11 Then
                    .Height = New GridLength(200, GridUnitType.Star)

                Else
                    .Height = New GridLength(35)
                End If
            End With
            vInnerGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(vRow)
        Next

        Dim UpperRow As New RowDefinition
        With UpperRow
            .Height = New GridLength(35)
        End With
        Dim MiddleRow As New RowDefinition
        With MiddleRow
            .Height = New GridLength(200, GridUnitType.Star)
        End With
        Dim BottomRow As New RowDefinition
        With BottomRow
            .Height = New GridLength(35)
        End With
        With Website_WebPage_Grid
            .RowDefinitions.Add(UpperRow)
            .RowDefinitions.Add(MiddleRow)
            .RowDefinitions.Add(BottomRow)
        End With

        Dim vToolBar As New ToolBar
        With vToolBar
            .Height = 35
        End With
        Grid.SetRow(vToolBar, 0)


        Website_WebPage_Grid.Children.Add(vToolBar)


        Dim EditButton As New Button
        If NewRecord = False Then

            With EditButton
                .Content = ReturnToolBarImage("Edit.png")
                .ToolTip = "Edit the record"
                .Name = "WebsiteWebPage_EditButton"
            End With
            RegisterControl(Website_WebPage_Grid, EditButton, EditButton.Name.ToString)
            vToolBar.Items.Add(EditButton)
            vToolBar.Items.Add(TS_Separator)
        End If

        Dim SaveUpdateButton As New Button
        With SaveUpdateButton
            .Name = "WebsiteWebPage_SaveUpdateButton"
            If NewRecord = True Then
                .Content = ReturnToolBarImage("Record_Insert.png")
                .ToolTip = "Save the record"
            Else
                .Content = ReturnToolBarImageGrey("Record_Update.png")
                .ToolTip = "Update the record"
                .IsEnabled = False
            End If
        End With
        RegisterControl(Website_WebPage_Grid, SaveUpdateButton, SaveUpdateButton.Name.ToString)
        vToolBar.Items.Add(SaveUpdateButton)
        vToolBar.Items.Add(TS_Separator)


        Dim OutPutLB As New Label
        With OutPutLB
            .Name = "WebsiteAdministrator_OutputLB"
            .HorizontalAlignment = Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Right
            .VerticalAlignment = Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center
            .FontSize = 10
        End With
        RegisterControl(Website_WebPage_Grid, OutPutLB, OutPutLB.Name.ToString)
        Grid.SetColumnSpan(OutPutLB, 2)
        Grid.SetRow(OutPutLB, 0)
        vInnerGrid.Children.Add(OutPutLB)

        Dim vName As String = "WebsiteAdministrator_"
        For i As Integer = 1 To 7
            Dim vLabel As New Label
            With vLabel
                .FontSize = 10
                .VerticalAlignment = Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center
                .HorizontalAlignment = Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left
            End With
            Dim vTB As New CustomControl.TBx
            With vTB
                .IsNewRecord = NewRecord
                '.Width = 200
            End With
            Select Case i
                Case 1
                    vLabel.Content = "Page Name"
                    With vTB
                        .Width = 200
                        .Name = vName & "PageNameTB"
                    End With
                Case 2
                    vLabel.Content = "Meta Description"
                    With vTB
                        .Width = 600
                        .Name = vName & "MetaDescriptionTB"
                    End With
                Case 3
                    vLabel.Content = "Title"
                    With vTB
                        .Width = 400
                        .Name = vName & "TitleTB"
                    End With
                Case 4
                    vLabel.Content = "Navigate URL"
                    With vTB
                        .Width = 400
                        .Name = vName & "NavigateURLTB"
                    End With
                Case 5
                    vLabel.Content = "Menu Text"
                    With vTB
                        .Width = 200
                        .Name = vName & "MenuTextTB"
                    End With
                Case 6
                    vLabel.Content = "Menu ToolTip"
                    With vTB
                        .Width = 400
                        .Name = vName & "MenuToolTipTB"
                    End With
                Case 7
                    vLabel.Content = "Menu Position"
                    With vTB
                        .Width = 100
                        .Name = vName & "MenuPositionTB"
                    End With

            End Select
            Grid.SetColumn(vLabel, 0)
            Grid.SetRow(vLabel, i)
            Grid.SetColumn(vTB, 1)
            Grid.SetRow(vTB, i)
            vInnerGrid.Children.Add(vLabel)
            vInnerGrid.Children.Add(vTB)


        Next

        Grid.SetRow(vScrollViewer, 1)
        Website_WebPage_Grid.Children.Add(vScrollViewer)


        Dim DP As DockPanel = PageStatusBarDP(Website_WebPage_Grid)
        Grid.SetRow(DP, 2)
        Grid.SetColumnSpan(DP, 2)
        Website_WebPage_Grid.Children.Add(DP)


    Catch ex As Exception
        EmailError(ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```